# Breeze.js - QueryLocal - search Function

Tags: breeze

I want do realise a search function in an WebApi project.
But how to execute a localQuery?

I have tried:

```
var EntityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery;
var FilterQueryOp = breeze.FilterQueryOp;
var Predicate = breeze.Predicate;    
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);
```

But what is the serviceName in my case?

Comment: I'm glad Jay understands this question. I sure don't. Would you please edit your question and elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any serviceName, i.e. "foo", should do the trick. Just don't try to go remote without resetting it to something "real". Breeze will not use the serviceName until a remote service call actually occurs, so this is safe.